# Why are software downloads only categorized by OS and not architecture?

Tags: deployment, architecture, operating-system

When deploying software (particularly non managed code), obviously you are targeting an OS as well as a particular archtecture. However, when downloading software on the internet, architecture never seems to be relevant beyond 32-bit and 64 bit (presumably x86 and x86-64). Is this because there is an inherent assumption that most desktop computers run some flavor of x86 and get their software from the web while mobile devices that have ARM processors get their software from mobile stores, etc? I feel this is too big of an assumption.

Comment: I for one believe developers should include in the package name the bit-ness, OS, complete if abbreviated software name, and ver#.  Something like MySoftware-Winx64-V01.65.1.  This would be for 'MySoftware'  package for Windows x64  and the software version number is 01.65.1.  Developers for some reason always assume that the file will exist in some context where that context will always be available to deduce that information.  The reason so many don't is that the developers are so close to the action they assume everyone knows as much as they do about the specific package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not an assumption but manifestation of resource limitation on the developers part.

Porting software even to another operating system requires substantial amount of work because you have to make sure that your interface remains consistent. Porting to another architecture has many more implications.

Proprietary software belongs to some organisation which works for profit. So from their perspective it’s not worth the effort to port their software to a less used OS let alone a different architecture. For example photoshop is widely used but still it’s windows and Mac only because adobe doesn’t see any benefit in porting to Linux.

As for the free software which supports different architecture you will always find some link to binaries or the source.

In summary we can say that if you developed a new architecture why would other people write software for that until of course it becomes something like x86 or arm.